# OCaml Power Function

Tags: function, recursion, ocaml

I am trying to write Ocaml power function but i get an error . Here is my code below.

```
let rec power x n = 
if n = 0 then 1 
else x * power (x n-1)

Error: This expression has type int
       This is not a function; it cannot be applied.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive call to `power` is parenthesized incorrectly. You want this:

```
power x (n - 1)
```

The parse for what you have would be: `power ((x n) - 1)`. In other words, as the compiler is telling you, it tries to apply `x` as if it were a function.